# Uncaught exception with namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I am reading a book about php and I found this script that doesn't work:

```
namespace woo\controller {

    // woo\controller\ApplicationHelper;
    class ApplicationHelper {

        function getOptions() {
            if (!file_exists("data/woo_options_not_there.xml")) {
                $r = new \woo\base\AppException("Non riesco ad aprire il file<br>");
                throw new $r;
            }
            $options = simplexml_load_file("data/woo_options.xml");
            $dsn = (string) $options->dsn;
            print $dsn;
        }

    }

    $d = (new ApplicationHelper())->getOptions();
}

namespace woo\base {

    class AppException extends \Exception {

    }

}
```

Can you help me?

This is the mistake:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'woo\base\AppException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\9781430260318_Chapter_12_Code\listing12.00.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\9781430260318_Chapter_12_Code\listing12.00.php(20): woo\controller\ApplicationHelper->getOptions() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\9781430260318_Chapter_12_Code\listing12.00.php on line 11

Comment: it looks like it's your custom exception that's being thrown, so according to what you've shown the file `data/woo_options_not_there.xml` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

So let's follow the train of logic here

We're creating the class `ApplicationHelper` and then instantiating it. Then, we call `getOptions()` which looks for an XML file and, if it doesn't find it, throws an exception.

Your code is working fine, you just forgot to `catch` the exception (this produces a fatal PHP error)

```
try {
    $d = (new ApplicationHelper())->getOptions();
} catch(\woo\base\AppException $err) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $err->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but there are still two problems.
1.I can not read "Non riesco ad aprire il file<br>";
2.I can not read "print $dsn";

Comment: Check the path to the file and make sure it can be read by your web server

Comment: Sure, If I remove "if" condition the script work well.

Comment: Well, you're checking for a non-existent file and that check is succeeding. Why not check for the file you're actually using?